# yii2 app on online server:Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException The view file does not exist

Tags: php, web-applications, view, yii2

I uploaded YII2 advanced my web app to online server.

I have 2 tables(companies,employees) and generated CRUD for these 2 tables.In main menu navigation given to view of company.
the below code i given on `backend/views/layouts/main.php` for navigation.

```
 $menuItems = [
                 ['label' => 'HOME', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
                 ['label' => 'COMPANIES', 'url' => ['/companies/index']]  
                 ['label' => 'EMPLOYEES', 'url' => ['/employee/index']],

           ];
```

It's worked properly on `localhost`. But in online getting this exception.

> Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException The view file does
>   not exist:
>   /home/echosoft/public_html/echosoftware/backend/views/companies/index.php

The file is existing in that folder.Please help me to solve this issue. I am stuck with this for 3 days.

This is `backend\config.php` codes

```
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);


return [


    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
            'name' => 'advanced-backend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],




    ],
    'params' => $params,

];
```

This may help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
      ['label' => 'COMPANIES', 'url' => ['/companies/index']]
```

and if the localhost is windows and online server is unix/linux like  be sure you have the proper case in the pathname filename 
Windows in case insensitive in pathname unix is case sensitive

If in your `backend\views`   you have the folder name with uppercase (`backend\views\Companies`) you should change with lower case  (`backend\views\companies`) ..

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I used this code .Path was correct. ['label' => 'COMPANIES', 'url' => ['/companies/index']],It is not working.Please give your time to analys this problem.Thanks once again.

Comment: I tried the the code as  ['label' => 'COMPANIES', 'url' => ['/Companies/index']],Because View folder name is 'Companies'. That time 404 page not error coming

Comment: Thank you so much scaisEdge.  It is working perfectly.I changed the folder  name .It was backend\views\Companies.I changed it in to backened\views\companies.